# Slicing data in list

Tags: python

I have list of data like this:

```
data = ['Data_0',
  ['param_1', 0],
  ['param_2', 1],
  ['param_3', 3.14],
  ['param_n', 375],
  ['param_6' , 67],
  'Data_1',                                     
  ['param_1', 1],
  ['param_2', 2],
  ['param_3', 3.4],
  ['param_n', 6785],
  ['param_6',678],
  'Data_2',
  ['param_1', 1],
  ['param_2', 3],
  ['param_3', 2.19],
  ['param_n', 345],
  ['param_6', 675]]
```

I need code that slice list of data like this:

```
sliced_data_0 = [
'Data_0',
['param_1', 1],
['param_2', 2],
['param_3', 3.4],
['param_n', 6785],
['param_6',678],

sliced_data_1 = [
'Data_1',
['param_1', 1],
['param_2', 2],
['param_3', 3.4],
['param_n', 6225],
['param_6',678],

sliced_data_2 = [
'Data_2',
['param_1', 1],
['param_2', 2],
['param_3', 3.4],
['param_n', 12385],
['param_6',623],
```

I need some code that will work in loop

```
for i in data:
    update_method(sliced_data_[i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the length of sublists you'd like to split things into, you can use `yield` with vanilla python. Calling this from within a function and catching the result in `list()` lets you cut your data up into pieces.

```py
def slicep(arr):
  for i in range(0, len(arr), 4):
    yield arr[i:i + 4]

def update_method(arr):
  print(arr)


data = [1,[2, False],[3, 1],[4, 3.14],5,[6, True],[7, 0],[8, 2.19],9,[0, False],[1, 1],[2, 6.12]]

sliced_data = list(slicep(data))

for sublist in sliced_data:
  update_method(sublist)
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/AnxiousHotComment)

You can capture the result of `list()` into a variable, which will become a list of your sliced lists. You can then iterate through this and call `update_method()` on each entry.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(0, len(data), 4):
    update_method(data[i:i+4])
```

Or

```
for sub_data in zip(*(data[i::4] for i in range(4)))):
    update_method(sub_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You guys!
I just added method for count lines for slice:

```
def line_counter(data):
    block_count = 0
    line_count = 0
    for string in data:
        if type(string) is str:
            block_count += 1
        if type(string) is list and block_count == 1:
            line_count += 1
    return line_count


def slicer(data, count_of_lines_in_data):
    for string in data:
        if type(string) is str:
            data.remove(string)
    for i in range(0, len(data), count_of_lines_in_data):
        yield data[i:i + count_of_lines_in_data]

def update_method(sublist):
    print(sublist)



if __name__ == "__main__":


  data = ['Data_0',
  ['param_1', 0],
  ['param_2', 1],
  ['param_3', 3.14],
  ['param_n', 375],
  ['param_6' , 67],
  'Data_1',
  ['param_1', 1],
  ['param_2', 2],
  ['param_3', 3.4],
  ['param_n', 6785],
  ['param_6',678],
  'Data_2',
  ['param_1', 1],
  ['param_2', 3],
  ['param_3', 2.19],
  ['param_n', 345],
  ['param_6', 675]]

  count_of_lin = line_counter(data)

  sliced_data = list(slicer(data, count_of_lin))
  for sublist in sliced_data:
    update_method(sublist)
```

This is necessary because the number of parameters in the data list is not 4, but can vary.

[Demo](https://repl.it/@K1_reaLreaL/SardonicVerticalMotion-1)